# Can you use CFUserNotification with IOS 5.1

Tags: ios, notifications

I am trying to get a notification to appear when the app is in the background or suspented, as the LocalNotification does not work, I seen mention the CFUserNotification as a potential solution, but when i include the corefoundation framework to my app the CFUserNotification is still no-where to be found, can someone show me how to include CFUserNotification in my project ?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you use CFUserNotification with IOS 5.1?

No

Comment: Did it go away in 5.1, or are you commenting that it's not approved for **App Store** usage?  I have a 5.0 device that it still is available on.

Comment: @Nate there may be some references in the *binaries*, but the CFUserNotification APIs are not in the CoreFoundation headers (on iOS). thus, i'd assume that it's not part of the public APIs (and therefore private, if any symbols you need exist). that also explains my response 'No'. if you explain how *you* use it on the device, that could qualify as an answer…

Comment: thanks for the response.  that's what I needed.  I have a non-App Store app that uses `CFUserNotification`, but I haven't updated to 5.1 yet, so I just wanted to make sure that you weren't saying that it disappeared in 5.1.  it's private, and has been for some time.

Comment: @Nate you're welcome. i don't remember it ever being available (read: public) on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're not making this for the App Store**, you can use private APIs.  The way I have used CFUserNotifications is to

1. Add CoreFoundation.framework to the list of frameworks I link against (maybe this framework is automatically included ... I'm not sure ... I just know that it doesn't hurt to add it explicitly to your project).
2. The CoreFoundation public APIs still don't have the CFUserNotification functions in the headers, as Justin said.  So, you need to manually include a **complete** CFUserNotification.h header.  You can [find a copy here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFUserNotification.h).  Just copy that whole header file, and include it in your project source directory.  Then `#import "CFUserNotification.h"` where you want to use it.

Then, the compiler will let you access those `CFUserNotification` APIs.  I've done this on iOS 5.0 with success (on a device).