# CTCall callState method "unrecognized"

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, tweak

I'm working on a jailbreak tweak where I need to detect an incoming call. I can successfully get the CTCall object however, when I call `callState` to get the current state it throws up this error and crashes:

> Feb 23 12:56:07 iPhone-5 SpringBoard[23247] : CTCall: {status = 3, type = 0x1, uuid = 0x211bf240 [68952DF3-B9CF-4BAD-A538-B802B7B49CC8], address = 0x21164bb0, externalID = -1, start = 2.22507e-308, session start = 3.83317e+08, end = 2.22507e-308}
>
> Feb 23 12:56:07 iPhone-5 SpringBoard[23247] : **-[__NSCFType callState]: unrecognized selector** sent to instance 0x211c8c10
>
> Feb 23 12:56:07 iPhone-5 SpringBoard[23247] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType callState]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x211c8c10'

The first log line is just checking that there is indeed a CTCall object that I'm trying to call `callState` on. Clearly, there is a CTCall object so I don't understand why this is failing to work?

The exact code that is producing the above output:

```
 NSLog(@"CTCall: %@", call);

 NSLog(@"*** Value of CTCall state: %@", call.callState);
```

If anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this question still needs answering, but here's a reference to our other [question where we discuss a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765396/119114).