# iOS record phone calls audio on a jailbroken device

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I want to be able to record the audio of a phone call on a jailbroken iOS device.
I can think of two possible ways:
1)Start the microphone recorder once the phone call begins and record
2)Capture the actual audio stream of the phone call

Is any of the above possible? Ot any other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356453/rec-ios-conversations-where-to-start/19413363#19413363

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voice memo recorder only picks up audio from the microphone - therefore unless you are using speakerphone, it won't record the other person.

Comment: it might just suit my needs for now. What API should I use to detect incoming calls?

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka, take a look [at this answer to detect incoming calls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765396/119114).  Note that you might need to do what it suggests in the *comments* below the actual answer for iOS 6.