# Call notification iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, core-telephony

I was searching around `kCTCallStatusChangeNotification` and read that this is being called from CoreTelephony framework. However I went through the header files in the `Xcode` folders under public frameworks and saw no mentioning `kCTCallStatusChangeNotification` or even any private frameworks with `CTTelephonyCenter`. I tried dumping the headers for relevant private frameworks and still could not find the correct file to include. I am currently using iOS SDK 7.0
I read tutorials that makes use of CoreTelephony framework and that it was actually a private framework after which being transferred over to a public framework( from what I see in my current public framework folder). So how do I actually call this function/type and where is it being located?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @cdj I was reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356453/rec-ios-conversations-where-to-start but according to the accepted answer there this function is found in CTTelephonyCenter which i dont have any header files/libraries which has the same name. I hope I answered your question

Comment: I have used coreTelephony framework for getting notified whenever we get call.

Comment: Basically kCTCallStatusChangeNotification does a notification when the call status is changed rite? This function is supposed to be in the coretelephony framework but i cant find it anywhere with sdk 7.0. Is this function in the private or public framework folder for sdk7.0?

Comment: Yes you are right its not there in framework.I got it from [ios-reversed-headers](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers).May be it can help you.

Comment: I would like to know the source folder where they generate the reversed headers. If these headers are dumped, according to the readme, there must a library to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kCTCallStatusChangeNotification` is not a function, it's notification. You can import it from public CoreTelephony.framework like this

```
extern CFStringRef const kCTCallStatusChangeNotification;
```

Then read this [Intercepting phone call - iPhone (correct method to hook in CoreTelephony)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758413/intercepting-phone-call-iphone-correct-method-to-hook-in-coretelephony?rq=1)