# How to manipulate iOS conversation's streams?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, jailbreak, audio-recording

I found two very useful topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809347/how-can-i-record-conversation-phone-call-on-ios%23) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356453/rec-ios-conversations-where-to-start). But I need somehow to change speaker/mic stream. For example, apply some effects or stop audio from being played to user at all. So my question is not about recording, but about manipulation of audio in real. Is there the way I can achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: You can use my code and instead of saving samples to a file you can manipulate it somehow. My code hooks resampling process so you have full access to realtime audio streams.

Comment: @creker, I tried not to call AudioUnitProcess_orig, but user still hear sounds. So decided AudioUnitProcess is not even important fore MobilePhone and conversation. What do u think about that?