# iPhone App: "Inject" audio files into phone conversation

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

After Googleing and looking through StackOverflow, I  haven't found a suitable solution to "inject audio from an iPhone app into an ongoing phone conversation."

As an iPhone app dev newbie, I found [Intercepting phone call - iPhone (correct method to hook in CoreTelephony)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758413/intercepting-phone-call-iphone-correct-method-to-hook-in-coretelephony), but I don't want to do ant jailbreaking. I want my iPhone app to insert pre-recorded phrases and noise effects into an ongoing phone conversation.

Can anyone tell me where I would start with that? Any hints, links or just some "general direction" advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt this is supported by any official Apple API.

Comment: Yeah, this won't be possible. Apple has made clear and definitive choices to wall off stuff like phone calls from third-party apps. There are simply too many ways this would be used maliciously.

Comment: OK, that's very interesting to me. Thanks for your responses. So apps like Tape-A-Call are OK, because they don't actually interfere with the phone conversation? Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS security sandbox actively prevents any (non-Apple) app from injecting audio into another app, such as the Phone app, where inter-app audio is not explicitly supported.